# Ubuntu 16.04 software center doesn't have many apps

Tags: software-center

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit.

When I opened its software store, I found that it's not showing the apps I installed in Ubuntu 15.10 like Clementine, Gdebi package installer or synaptic package manager, dconf, acetoneiso etc.

I need these applications. How can I install them?

Comment: I have the same problem, and it's not fixed with any given answer. An example (to me) is FreeCAD, which is available with apt, but not with the Ubuntu Software Center. I also have had this with many other applications. Also, the software center still often does not recognize that an app I am viewing is actually already installed. Workaround: You can use `apt search appName` to search for the application and `sudo apt install exactPackageName` to install it.

Comment: To clearify the situation, please say if this is your situation: The software center looks normal, but there are packages missing (that are available via `apt`, though). If yes, we definitely have the same situation.

Comment: There are programs missing from the "Software Center" that are still in the repository, but I'm not sure why. Try searching the "Ubuntu Apps Directory" https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/ for any missing programs that you still want or need.

Comment: Is it the "Ubuntu Software Center" or "Ubuntu softwares"?
There is a HUGE difference (2 different programs) - but icon is the same.

Answer (score 5):

The Ubuntu Software app in Ubuntu does not have the same software in it as the classic Ubuntu Software Center has. Not only is there missing software in the Ubuntu Software app, but the Ubuntu Software app also has some GNOME software in it that the Ubuntu Software Center doesn't have. To be sure of finding all the available software, you need to have both the Ubuntu Software app and the Ubuntu Software Center installed. If you want to broaden your search to include snap packages in Ubuntu 16.04 and later, you have to search in the terminal to find available snap packages too.

### Ubuntu 18.04 and later

Ubuntu Software and Synaptic are the top two software apps in Ubuntu 18.04 and they complement each other in functionality.

It should be noted that because software can be installed from both of these two GUI applications, **only one** of the following two applications should be opened and used to install software at the same time.

- Ubuntu Software / Software – *gnome-software*
- Synaptic package manager – *synaptic*

### Ubuntu 17.04/17.10

- Ubuntu Software – *gnome-software*
- Synaptic package manager – *synaptic*
- Debian Package Search – *packagesearch*

Ubuntu 17.04 doesn't have Ubuntu Software Center in its default repositories. Synaptic Package Manager works fine in Ubuntu 17.04 and shows all the apps like Ubuntu Software Center does, however Synaptic does not provide the same rich user experience as Ubuntu Software.

When I searched for a way of improving the package search functionality in Ubuntu 17.04, I found Debian Package Search (*packagesearch*). Debian Package Search is a GUI for searching packages and viewing package information. Debian Package Search can be installed alongside Synaptic and Ubuntu Software to add additional search functionality to Ubuntu 17.04 and 17.10 (discontinued in 18.04 and later).

Search in Debian Package Search can be done by:

- pattern
- tags (based on the debtags system, a new way of categorizing
  Debian packages)
- files
- installed status
- orphaned packages

Additionally a lot of information about the packages is displayed, including the files belonging to them.

### Ubuntu 16.04/16.10

Ubuntu Software Center works fine in Ubuntu 16.04 and shows all the apps as it did in earlier versions of Ubuntu. Ubuntu Software Center can be installed in Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 16.10.

```
sudo apt install software-center
```

Comment: There is a "new" program called "Ubuntu softwares" which is TOTALLY different than "Ubuntu software center".
I upgraded from 15.10 to 16.10 (in reality it was fresh install) and I was missing the "Software center", because "Ubuntu Softwares" did not find MANY of my programs as well as offered many irrelevants to me. I installed "Ubuntu Software Center" (from "Ubuntu Softwares") so I have 2 orange sack in my launcher (I did not delete yet the "Ubuntu Softwares" to be on the safe side).

Comment: You did it the best way, because both Ubuntu Software and Ubuntu Software Center, despite having the same orange icon, each have software that the other application doesn't have, so you need to keep both of them.

Answer (score 4):

The new software center was a mess for the first couple of hours, and this faulty version doesn't seem to refresh itself while it keeps running in the background even after you've closed the window.

You can force quit it by invoking

`killall gnome-software`

When you start the software center again it should update and look like a proper software center.

It's actually a very nice program now.

Comment: I have a problem that might be related to the refreshing thing you mentioned. I installed a tool to tweak Unity via Software Center, and after restarting Software Center it doesn't seem to remember installing the tool. My Vim install persists, probably because I did it via Terminal. Also,  uninstalls via Software Center don't persist. Is this related to what you mentioned, or something separate? I'm running it out of VirtualBox, although that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: I'm afraid this is a completely seperate issue. The problem in this thread was fixed a few days after posting. You might want to open a seperate question for your problem though, it sounds annoying!

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same problem.  Until it is fixed, I suggest using Synaptic package manager.  All the packages are available there and it works very well.

sudo apt-get install synaptic

sudo apt-get install gksudo

gksudo synaptic

(it is safe to skip a step if already installed)

Search for your package (application) by name and right click and mark for install.  Then click apply.  You can uninstall by the same method.

Answer (score 0):

If the method above doesn't work you can try this:

First, open the terminal and type this:

```
ps aux | grep apt
```

You will get a result in a table form, we are interested in the apt requests that contain the words `http` or `software` in them.

Once you find it, look at the second column. For example this is how it might look like:

```
username   2514  0.0  0.0  21376   948 pts/1    S+   22:37   0:00 apt-http
```

The results you get will be similar, but not exactly the same.

Now, we want the second column for the above result: that's `2514` for me. Add it here (put the number you just got instead of 2514)

```
sudo kill 2514
```

Repeat the commands until you get no more unnecessary requests (chances are you will have to do it only once).

Now start the ubuntu software and it should work!

Answer (score 0):

Removing unused dependency packages solved this problem for me.

To do this

- open a Terminal (using the Dash menu or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and
- type or insert `sudo apt autoremove` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- You will be asked for your users password. You will not see anything while typing, this is normal and a security feature.
- Now, restart the software center and try to search your packages.

I hope it works as well for you as it did for me. Unfortunately I have no idea which package caused this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues and I tried all the solutions mentioned above and no luck! Every time I click on the `Software Center` icon, it shows very few applications and I don't find common applications like `Geany`, `Filezilla`, and so on. On my laptop, I have the same version of `Ubuntu 16.04` and there I find all applications by clicking on the `Software Center` icon. Finally, I started the Software Center from the command line and it loaded with all applications, thank God!

**Solution** (Open software center from terminal instead of clicking on the icon):

```
shoeb@shoeb-OptiPlex-980:~$ software-center
```

[image: How to Open Ubuntu Software Center 16.04]