# Can't Find the Ubuntu Software Center After upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, software-center

I upgraded my Linux Ubuntu to Ubuntu 18.04 and Software Center seems to be missing. I tried to install from Command line. 
But I endup with the following Error.

```
> user@user-HP-ProBook-450-G2:~$ sudo apt-get install software-center
> [sudo] password for user:  Reading package lists... Done Building
> dependency tree        Reading state information... Done Package
> software-center is not available, but is referred to by another
> package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
> obsoleted, or is only available from another source
> 
> E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate
> user@user-HP-ProBook-450-G2:~$ ^C user@user-HP-ProBook-450-G2:~$
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does Package <package> has no installation candidate mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean) and [Ubuntu 16.04 software center doesn't have much apps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761126/ubuntu-16-04-software-center-doesnt-have-much-apps)

Answer (score 4):

Your commands are wrong for both, it's:

```
sudo apt-get install software-center*
```

with an asterisk (*) at the end, and the same with:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software*
```

However the store constant crashes and currently won't allow or stay open long enough to install software, it's a broken mess.

Answer (score 1):

it happened to me too after installing GNOME tweak. What I did was I install GNOME software and the software center reappeared on my dock (as I favorite it)

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```