# Can't find the Ubuntu software center

Tags: software-center

Somehow, I can't find the Ubuntu software center. Is it possible to reinstall it? Starting `software-center` on console fails due to

```
The program 'software-center' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install software-center
```

Comment: eh does the last part not tell you what to do?

Comment: do you have 'ubuntu-software' installed? that's the new name for it, but you don't say what version of ubuntu you're running

Comment: i have 16.04 LTS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.04 software center doesn't have much apps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761126/ubuntu-16-04-software-center-doesnt-have-much-apps)

Answer (score 2):

`software-center` was abbandoned in 16.04 in favour of `gnome-software`. You should use that. If you really want to install the old one type `sudo apt install software-center` in a terminal as the last line from the error message  says.

Answer (score 0):

Do what last line says!

`sudo apt install software-center`

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Software Center Sucks.

Use AppGrid instead. Installation Procedure :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:appgrid/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install appgrid
```

Still want to use Ubuntu Software Center? Follow @Vishesh Gautam instructions.