# The GNOME Software center shows few apps

Tags: gnome, gnome-software

so, now the GNOME software center shows few apps. All I did is install a few apps, mostly games like Five or more, Connect 4, apps like Evolution, that email client, then uninstalled them and now I have fewer apps than before available to install.
Killing `gnome-software` won't fix it. Seems nobody has reported this in this Q&A, so here it goes some proof.
[image]

How do I make it so it shows more apps like audio stuff?
(yes I'm spanish don't judge me please)
PD None of the answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761126/ubuntu-16-04-software-center-doesnt-have-much-apps) work. I've tried them and it still has only got 8 apps.

Afterwards I've got this tough dude in the lower corner of the screen:[image]

Translated means: 
"An error has occurred while checking for updates".
Now I did what it said [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761126/ubuntu-16-04-software-center-doesnt-have-much-apps) and it's worse. Thanks, reporters!
Anyway, I made sure that my system was up-to-date, it is. And so, the icon is still there.

Reinstalling won't help either, stuff is still the same after a purge reinstall.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.04 software center doesn't have much apps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761126/ubuntu-16-04-software-center-doesnt-have-much-apps)

Comment: Maybe you could expand on "All I did is install a few apps then uninstalled them and boom!" Which were these "few apps"?

Comment: @Jos Killing gnome-software doesn't help the issue.

Comment: Same issue after installing updated. I have killed the gnome-software. But not helpful. It reappears once software centre restart.

Comment: The red exclamation point in your lower left screen indicates there is a problem with your package management. You will need to fix that first. The command "sudo apt update" probably will give you error messages.

Answer (score 2):

I meet the same problem. And I find a solution on another forum thread. It is work on my computer. The below is taken from another thread.

```
$pkill gnome-software
$sudo rm -r /var/cache/app-info
$sudo appstreamcli refresh --force --verbose
```

[The link of solution from](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052768/my-ubuntu-software-doesnt-show-installed-programs-or-available-programs-any-mor)

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same and this is not an answer but an observation. All the packages it shows are *snap* packages, if you `search` is only lists *snap* packages, if you look at `installed` it only shows installed *snap* packages.

(I would rather put this in a comment but I've not enough reputation to do that)

Comment: I don't use the software center for snap packages, but all packages, .deb inclued.

Comment: @RazorManage89 me too , the observation I made is that , the few apps gnome-software is showing now are only *snap* packages  and not all other packages as it used to

Comment: which is the bug, gnome-software should show all packages `.deb` included.