# What happened to apps.ubuntu.com?

Tags: support

I tried to place an *install it* link into an answer, but apps.ubuntu.com went away and stopped working, it redirects to the Snapcraft store now.

The image was there all right but the link was redirected to https://snapcraft.io/store -- this isn't really what we want.

What happened to apps.ubuntu.com?  Is there a new place where Ubuntu software can be found?

Comment: I use [AptURL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptURL), e.g.: `[\`xdotool\` ![Install xdotool](https://hostmar.co/software-small)](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool)`

Comment: @dessert: Shouldn't that be `apt:xdotool` with AptURL rather than `http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool`?

Comment: @sondra.kinsey good point, I copied it myself… I guess it’s a more reliable link version as explained under “For websites that malform apt: links” [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AptUrl). Needless to say `apt:xdotool` works as well.

Comment: NOTE: I revised the content to make it more generic and not site-specific.  Also made it ask about apps.ubuntu.com rather than focusing on Meta/site-specific bits

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Ubuntu Software Center [was discontinued in 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Software_Center). It was replaced with GNOME Software (rebranded as Ubuntu Software) - so unfortunately the old links to **apps.ubuntu.com** do not work anymore . The new standard for software from an app-store like interface under Ubuntu is ["snaps" from snapcraft](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2016/06/14/universal-snap-packages-launch-on-multiple-linux-distros) and not deb packages any more - that's why you get redirected.

See also the last paragraph of [this answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/869710/783023).

Comment: FYI only mods can migrate questions ;)  (Flag it accordingly next time)

Comment: Just because a product is discontinued does not mean that all the links have to break. It is possible for web developers to set up sensible redirects.