# How do I install a non-standard Package Manager on Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, packaging

I want to know where the package manager is installed in Ubuntu. I know that it is pre-installed but I still want to know. I want to check it manually. Is there a directory or is it a kernel module, what is it?

I want to install it in the same way apt is installed on Ubuntu. I want to use it in the same terminal along with `apt`. I am just doing it for learning and experiment and I am doing all of this on virtual machine.

Comment: We don't usually answer multiple questions, nor "any linux distribution" questions. Try each of your questions in the Search box at the top of the page. These are beginner questions, so if you are a beginner at Linux, 1) DON'T assume that wherever you are coming from is "right". Keep an open mind to new ways on a new OS. 2) DO use the native tools the way they are intended to be used. Don't try to force a tool to behave in a way that is familiar with from your previous experience (See #1).

Comment: Ubuntu has two *default* package managers depending on what Ubuntu product you install. This isn't a Linux support/Q&A site, but a Ubuntu site, thus only Ubuntu products are on-topic here.  The default *package* type is *deb* based if you're using a *year.month* product (eg. 22.04) where as the only package type is *snap* if you're using a *year* product (eg. 22) as those are *snap* only.  That applies to Ubuntu products on-topic on this site.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 software center doesn't have many apps](https://askubuntu.com/q/761126/)

Comment: With respect, you sound like a novice user. I'd strongly urge you to reconsider installing non-standard package managers like `dnf` and `pacman` on Ubuntu. It's really not designed to be done, and can lead to quite a mess.

Comment: Please be aware that if you use other package managers, you might end up messing everything, and may have to reinstall Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu applications installed by the system are located at `/usr/bin`.

Ubuntu has two default package managers: `apt` and `snap`. And they're both located inside `/usr/bin`:

```
$ which apt
/usr/bin/apt

$ which snap
/usr/bin/snap
```

This is the default and completely expected for most GNU/Linux distributions.

##### Installing other package managers

Both `dnf` and `pacman` are included in the Ubuntu `universe` repository - meaning that volunteers have compiled and packaged it for use directly in Ubuntu.

For starters, make sure to [enable the Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository).

To install another package manager in the first place, you simply install it with `apt` like any other application. And afterwards, the new package manager is available to you.

###### DNF

The [`dnf` package manager](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/dnf) is available since Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy). It can be installed with:

```
sudo apt install dnf
```

You can check its location afterwards:

```
$ which dnf
/usr/bin/dnf
```

###### Pacman

The [`pacman` package manager](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/pacman-package-manager) is available since Ubuntu 22.10 (Kinetic). It can be installed with:

```
sudo apt install pacman-package-manager
```

You can check its location afterwards:

```
$ which pacman
/usr/bin/pacman
```